# Somersd function from scipy.stats produces type error in Python

Tags: python, pivot-table, scipy.stats, gini

I would like to calculate the somers d.
I have the following input cross table in python as a data frame called crosstab:

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 80 | 100 | 4 | 500 |
| 50 | 3 | 2 | 0 | 38 |
| 40 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 40 |
| 2000 | 100 | 100 | 4 | 400 |

I try to calculate the sommers d and get the following error message:

```
from scipy.stats import somersd
somersd(crosstab)
```

> `TypeError`: Invalid call to pythranized function
> `_concordant_pairs(int64[:, :] (with unsupported column-major
> layout))' Candidates are:
> - _concordant_pairs(int[:,:])
> - _concordant_pairs(float[:,:])

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) because `x`  in [`somersd`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.somersd.html) should be an *array-like* of floats :

```
out = somersd(x=crosstab.astype(float).to_numpy())
```

​
Output :

```
print(out)

SomersDResult(
        statistic=-0.5710103041724046,
        pvalue=9.019579189415401e-226,
        table=array([[ 100.,   80.,  100.,    4.,  500.],
       [  50.,    3.,    2.,    0.,   38.],
       [  40.,    0.,    4.,    0.,   40.],
       [2000.,  100.,  100.,    4.,  400.]]))
```

*Input used :*

```
crosstab = pd.DataFrame(
    {0: [100, 50, 40, 2000],
     1: [80, 3, 0, 100],
     2: [100, 2, 4, 100],
     3: [4, 0, 0, 4],
     4: [500, 38, 40, 400]}
)
```